# Xamarin Forms item classification with converter

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ivalueconverter

I need to classify a list of item in my PCL app.
The classification must be between values 0 and 3.
I need 3 togglebutton, one for each value of the classification.
So if the value of the item classification is 2, the first two togglebutton isToggled property must be true, and the third false.
If the value of the item classification is 3, all three togglebutton isToggled property must be true.
Viceversa, if I toggle to true the isToggled property of the second togglebutton I want that the classification value must be 2, and the rest of the togglebutton update according to this value.
The problem is that for example when I toggle to true the third button.
The selected slot change correctly to T3, so others button have to refresh their isToggledProperty. For example the first togglebutton must change is IsToggled property to true. This happens, but this changing of the isToggledProperty of the first togglebutton, cause again the changing of the selected slot, that change again the Istoggled property of the togglebuttonbutton to false.

[image: screenshot]

This is my togglebutton that represent the 3 value  of the classification.

```
    var t3 = new BoxView
    {
        Color = Color.FromHex("#00d2ff")
    };
    var t3ToggleBehavior = new ToggleBoxBehavior();
    t3ToggleBehavior.SetBinding(ToggleBoxBehavior.IsToggledProperty, new Binding("SelectedSlot", BindingMode.TwoWay, new SelectedSlotToBooleanConverter(), converterParameter: "T3"));
    t3.Behaviors.Add(t3ToggleBehavior);
    var t3trigger = new DataTrigger(typeof(BoxView))
    {
        Binding = new Binding
        {
            Source = t3ToggleBehavior,
            Path = "IsToggled"
        },
        Value = false
    };
    t3trigger.Setters.Add(new Setter
    {
        Property = BoxView.ColorProperty,
        Value = Color.FromHex("#eeeeee")
    });
    t3.Triggers.Add(t3trigger);
    grid.Children.Add(t3, 0, 0);
```

The 3 togglebutton different only for the converter parameter (T1 o T2)

This is my converter

```
public class SelectedSlotToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo language)
{
    if (value != null && parameter != null)
    {
        var val = fromString(value.ToString());
        var par = fromString(parameter.ToString());
        return val >= par;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo language)
{
    if (parameter != null)
    {
        return fromString(parameter.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        return parameter;
    }
}

private Slot fromString(string slot)
{

        switch (slot)
        {
            case "T1":
                return Slot.T1;
            case "T2":
                return Slot.T2;
            case "T3":
                return Slot.T3;
            default:
                return Slot.Off;

        }
}
}
```

This is my ToggleBoxBehavior

```
   public class ToggleBoxBehavior : Behavior<View>
{
TapGestureRecognizer tapRecognizer;

public static readonly BindableProperty IsToggledProperty = BindableProperty.Create<ToggleBehavior, bool>(tb => tb.IsToggled, false);

public bool IsToggled
{
    set { SetValue(IsToggledProperty, value); }
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsToggledProperty); }
}

protected override void OnAttachedTo(BindableObject bindable)
{
    base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
    this.BindingContext = bindable.BindingContext;
    bindable.BindingContextChanged += Bindable_BindingContextChanged;
}

void Bindable_BindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var bobject = sender as BindableObject;

    this.BindingContext = bobject?.BindingContext;
}


protected override void OnAttachedTo(View view)
{
    base.OnAttachedTo(view);

    tapRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
    tapRecognizer.Tapped += OnTapped;
    view.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapRecognizer);
}

protected override void OnDetachingFrom(View view)
{
    base.OnDetachingFrom(view);

    view.GestureRecognizers.Remove(tapRecognizer);
    tapRecognizer.Tapped -= OnTapped;
}

void OnTapped(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    IsToggled = !IsToggled;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please put a screenshot of what you are trying to do so it is easier to imagine ?

Comment: I add the screenshot

Comment: Well it might not be the best help , but maybe it can give you some hints . When I saw your screenshot for some reason I Xamarin.Froms ProgressBar crossed my mind , (except that it is horizontal rather than vertical) . 
So for me , instead of having 3 different controls to represent a value , why not make one control that consists of three parts, and the control has a value can be set and can control the parts ?

Comment: I can't understand how a user can set the value of the progressbar

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ProgressBar/

here you have all what you need to know about ProgressBar

Answer (score 0):

i know, thats pretty late, but
we added a ToggleButton into our [NuGet!](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AscendantWare.Xamarin.Essentials/)
Its free to use.

```
xmlns:aw="clr-namespace:AscendantWare.Xamarin.Essentials.Controls"

<aw:AWToggleButton TextColor="White" ToggleBackgroundColor="DarkGoldenrod" Margin="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Fill" CornerRadius="15" IsToggled="{Binding IsNoteEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
```

You can binde the IsToggled-Property and write your own logic in the set-function in your viewmodel.

More Informations in our online documentation [here!](https://ascendantware.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/articles/AWXE-A-8/ToggleButton)